# How to query the inner object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Below is the MongoDB document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d7021544ae418347b807e6"),
    "_class" : "ead.cs.domain.ShipSchedule",
    "ship" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55d6e4ed44ae8b2f121c2e55"),
        "referenceId" : "1",
        "name" : "Dasun Ship",
        "description" : "Desv"
    },
    "departureDate" : ISODate("2015-08-20T18:30:00Z"),
    "arrivalDate" : ISODate("2015-08-29T18:30:00Z"),
    "departurePort" : "Colombo",
    "arrivalPort" : "India",
    "distance" : 100,
    "arDate" : "30/08/2015",
    "deDate" : "21/08/2015"
}
```

How can I fetch this document by provided ship's objectId?

I tried below but didn't work

```
db.shipSchedules.findOne(ObjectId("55d6e4ed44ae8b2f121c2e55")).pretty();


db.shipSchedules.findOne("ship":ObjectId("55d6e4ed44ae8b2f121c2e55")).pretty();
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.shipSchedules.findOne({ "ship._id":ObjectId("55d6e4ed44ae8b2f121c2e55")})
```

Comment: This give me SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: it gives me TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pretty'

Comment: Tx. will accept this as the answer